# undefined behaviour when trying to print array elements

Tags: arrays, c, memory

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  char names[3][5]={{'a','b','c','d','\0'},{'e','f','g','h','\0'},{'k','l','m','n','\0'}};
  char (*x)[5];

  for(x=names;x<=x+2;x++){
    printf("%s\n",*x);
  }
}
```

the goals of this code is to `printf` the strings in this 2d array, but the output is really weird. It is the first time I see something like this.

ouptut:

```
> 
> abcd
> efgh
> klmn
> �=3�
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> I8V
> 
> 
> 3�
> 
> �
> ��.m�
> �
> 
> ?3�
> 
> zI8V
> 
> 
> ��HU�yԁB��7x
> �yԁB��7x
> B��7x
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> �
> 
> ���
> 
> 
> 
> �yI8V
> 
> I8V
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> ��p��C�x86_64
> �C�x86_64
> x86_64
> 4
> 
> 
> /strcat
> at
> ELL=/bin/bash
> bin/bash
> ash
> ESSION_MANAGER=local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> N_MANAGER=local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> AGER=local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> /kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> :@/tmp/.ICE-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> p/.ICE-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> E-unix/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> x/836,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> ,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> /kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> :/tmp/.ICE-unix/836
> /.ICE-unix/836
> -unix/836
> /836
> WINDOWID=0
> WID=0
> 
> CCESSIBILITY=1
> IBILITY=1
> TY=1
> COLORTERM=truecolor
> TERM=truecolor
> truecolor
> olor
> XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
> ONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
> _DIRS=/etc/xdg
> =/etc/xdg
> /xdg
> XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
> ESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
> N_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
> H=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
> g/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
> edesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
> top/DisplayManager/Session0
> isplayManager/Session0
> yManager/Session0
> ger/Session0
```

Could you explain the meaning of that output and why am I getting it?

### edit

Now I understand where I made the mistake, but anyway I want to know where does that output come.

Comment: Typo. `x<=x+2` will always be true.

Comment: thank you i edit it,but can you explaine what is that output,it seem like it read some file configuration!!

Comment: Because your pointer flies off to infinity and is dereferenced when it's pointing at other strings in your compiled binary. Maybe. It happens to act this way for this compiler, this version, on your computer. It could behave completely dfferently the next time you compile, or when the compiler updates, or on my computer. In general, it's a waste of time to reason about undefined behavior.

Comment: It looks like your stray pointer ended up printing your process's [*environment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).  Try typing the `printenv` command.  You should see similar strings.

Comment: Note that `char names[3][5]={{'a','b','c','d','\0'},{'e','f','g','h','\0'},{'k','l','m','n','\0'}};` is a long-winded and hard way of writing `char name[3][5] = { "abcd", "efgh", "klmn" };` (and what happened to `i` and `j`?).

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char names[3][5] = {{'a','b','c','d','\0'},{'e','f','g','h','\0'},{'k','l','m','n','\0'}};
    char (*x)[5];

    //                   +- HERE
    //                   |
    for (x = names; x <= x + 2; x++) {
        printf("%s\n", *x);
    }
}
```

The problem is that you compare the value of `x` to itself.
The expression `x <= x + 2` can never be `false`.
The value of `x` is reevaluated for each occurrence in the expression, not just the left side.
You should store the result of `x + 2` in a variable and use that variable on the right side of the expression.

Comment: thank you ,but please read the modified publication

Comment: `x <= x + 2` can be false when `x + 2` is out of bounds and the behavior is not defined.

Comment: After some iterations the pointer points to an uninitialized location in memory. The output is just some leftover data that happens to be at that location. The leftover data highly depends on circumstances and will probably change each time you execute the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if overflow is undefined, it's not accurate to say that it can be false. At that point, it's outside the bounds of a normal program. Any modern compiler with optimizations turned on would probably optimize the entire comparison away. Is pointer overflow undefined behavior in C, though?

Comment: @JohnFilleau: Yes, it is accurate to say it can be false. “Undefined behavior” means the C standard allows anything (it imposes no requirements), so it can be false. Yes, pointer overflow has undefined behavior. The behavior of an addition that would not produce a result inside the relevant object it to just beyond its end is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil fair. Reasonable people will differ on opinion, and we are probably approaching from different viewpoints. Since it's UB, the compiler is free to assume it will never be false. My "will always be true" should be taken as "will always be true as far as the compiler is concerned".

Answer (score 1):

You wondered where those "weird strings" came from.  They look like fragments of a typical Unix/Linux process environment, which consists of a list of name/value pairs known as [*environment variables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Normally you access these strings in a C program by using the [`getenv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) function, but they are contained in an array of strings (similar to your program's arguments `argv`) copied in to your process's address space when it is exec'ed.  Under most Unix-like systems you can peek at the raw environment strings using code like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    char *p;
    for(p = *envp;; p++) putchar(*p);
}
```

or

```
extern char **environ;

int main()
{
    char *p;
    for(p = *environ;; p++) putchar(*p);
}
```

Those are both quickly and crudely written, and sail off the end of the environment and eventually crash (as indeed your program did).  A cleaner way of printing the environment would be

```
char **v;
char *p;
for(v = environ; *v != NULL; v++) {
    for(p = *v; *p != '\0'; p++) putchar(*p);
    putchar('\n');
}
```